# Inactive / Activate : basic question of how it works

Tags: hold

I would like to understand how Inactive and Activate function works because I'm disturbed.

If I need to inactivate a function and then re activate it how to do it ?
I tried the following which doesn't work :

```
hh[x_] := x^2

hh[2]

4

hh = Inactive[hh]

Inactive[hh]

hh[2]

Inactive[hh][2]

hh = Activate[hh]

Inactive[hh]

hh[2]

Inactive[hh][2]
```

As you can see the function isn't reactivated as I would like it to be. I would like to understand why because it would help me to understand better how activate/inactivate functions work.

Comment: if you use a different name for `Inactive[hh]` (e.g. `hh1 =Inactive[hh]`, `Activate[hh1[2]]`gives 4 as expected.

Comment: @kglr but why isn't it working as I wrote it ? Indeed in hh=Activate[hh] I would expexct mathematica to expand the rhs which would mean : hh=Activate[Inactive[hh]] thus "in a way:" hh[x]=Activate[Inactive[x^2]]=x^2. I am writing it roughly for you to see how I understand the code to give you an idea of where my misunderstanding would be

Comment: Defining a thing in terms of itself is not a good idea if you don't want to do recursion. For example, try `hh = List[hh]`: you'll see that Mathematica complains about recursion depth. The only reason that doesn't happen with `Inactive` is because of the `HoldFirst` attribute, but it's still not a good idea to do self-referential definitions like the one you posted. The only time you can do that is when `hh` actually has a value, such as with `x = 1;  x = x + 1`. In that case, the self-reference is broken because `x` will evaluate to its value on the r.h.s.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit ok maybe I'm too much used to other programming language. In mathematica I should avoid to do it. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

When you say `hh = Inactive[hh]`, it means "whenever you see `hh`, rewrite it as `Inactive[hh]`. Once you've made that definition, it becomes very hard to activate `hh` because when `Activate` yields `hh`, it immediately gets rewritten as `Inactive[hh]`.

Look at `Trace[hh = Activate[hh]]`. The rewrite defeats your attempt to redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give an example using related commands in an approach that has been useful to me. Specifically **Inactivate** and **Activate**.

Suppose you are working with a matrix expression and trying to understand what is going on. Or want to show work step-by-step as might be required in a homework problem or research derivation. This answer pertains to the original "basic question of how it works" posed by @StarBucK.

```
A = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{Pi, E, Sqrt[2]}}
```

and you want to form

```
A.Transpose[A].Inverse[A]
```

Actually here's a series of input lines to Mathematica

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {Pi, E, Sqrt[2]}}

A // TraditionalForm

Inactivate[A.Transpose[A].Inverse[A]] // TraditionalForm

Activate[%, Transpose] // TraditionalForm

Activate[%, Inverse] // TraditionalForm

Activate[%, Dot] // TraditionalForm

% // N // TraditionalForm
```

My output in Mathematica 13.3.0.0 is

[image]